# Show the bounds are sharp in $\text L_p$ norms by exhibiting instances of equality

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

> It is easy to see that, for any *n*-vector *x*, the $\text L_p$ norms have the relationships $\|x\|_\infty \le \|x \|_2 \le \|x\|_1$. *Show that the bounds are sharp by exhibiting instances of equality*. More generally, for given *x* and for $p\ge 1$, we see that $\|x\|_p$ is a nonincreasing function of *p*.

Comparing $\text L_\infty$ and $\text L_1$ norms:

$$\|x\|_\infty=\max_i |x_i|\le \max_i |x_i|+\color{green}{\sum_{j\ne i}|x_j|}=\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|=\|x\|_1$$

Comparing $\text L_2$ and $\text L_1$ norms:

$$\|x\|_2=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \text { vs } \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|=\|x\|_1\\
\text{Square both sides: }\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \text { vs } \left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2+\color{green}{2\sum_{i\ne j}|x_ix_j|}$$

hence the "vs" is $\le$.

Comparing $\text L_\infty$ and $\text L_2$ norms:

$$\|x\|_\infty=\max_i|x_i|\text { vs } \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}=\|x\|_2\\
\left(\max_i |x_i|\right)^2 \le \left(\max_i |x_i|\right)^2+\color{green}{\sum_{j\ne i}x_j^2}$$

I see there is equality if $x=(a,0,\dots,0)$, then $\|x\|_\infty=\|x\|_2=\|x\|_1=|a|$.
This corresponds to the three green terms above being zero. If there is at least one other nonzero term in the *n*-vector, then the green terms will be nonzero and we will have strict inequality. Is this what "show that the bounds are sharp by exhibiting instances of equality" means?

Also, this might be asking too much in one question, but how to show that $\|x\|_p$ is a nonincreasing function of *p*? I get

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^{q}\right)^{1/q} \text{ vs } \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^{p}\right)^{1/p} $$

but due to the interplay of exponents and summations the algebraic steps are not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you gave for equalities are right and they show that we can't get a stronger inequality like for example $\| x \|_{\infty} \leq 0.5\| x\|_2$.

edit: Sorry i deleted my answer to the second question. What i wrote was nonsense. Maybe i have a look at it tomorrow

Comment: Thank you! My book says $f(ax+(1-a)y)\le af(x)+(1-a)f(y)$ if *f* is convex but the answer seems to have the inequality switched. 
Ahh okay thank you.